# SQL query lost perfomance after adding filter with subselect

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a function that totally lost it's performance after i added another filter to it in postgresql

Here is a simple example of how it looked like at first with good performance.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(param_a boolean, param_b boolean )
     RETURNS TABLE(blablabla)
     LANGUAGE sql
     IMMUTABLE
    AS $function$
    with data as (
    select id,amount,account_nr from transfer
    )
    select * from 
    data d
    where  param_a or 0.00 <> (select sum(d2.amount)
                            from data d2
                            where d2.id = d.id)
    $function$
    ;
```

```
    (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=560)  
    (actual time=1162.528..1162.561 rows=306 loops=1)  
    Buffers: shared hit=1099180  
    Planning time: 2.928 ms  
    Execution time: 1162.630 ms
```

After i added another filter with a subselect and count i lost my perfomance. Is this count so bad for performance and can i solve it another way?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(param_a boolean, param_b boolean )
 RETURNS TABLE(blablabla)
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
with data as (
select id,amount,account_nr from transfer
)
select * from 
data d
where (param_b or 1 < (select count(d2.account_nr) 
                        from data d2
                        where d2.id = d.id
                        group by d2.account_nr))
and (param_a or 0.00 <> (select sum(d2.amount)
                        from data d2
                        where d2.id = d.id))
$function$
;
```

```
    (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=560)  
    (actualtime=271191.341..271191.383 rows=306 loops=1)  
    Buffers: shared hit=1099180  
    Planning time: 2.955 ms 
    Execution time: 271191.463 ms
```

Comment: Could you share the query plans for both queries (the query within the function that is) using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) ? And why do you use a CTE?

Comment: This is common antipattern - using clauses like boolvar or .. Use dynamic SQL or UNION ALL instead OR predicate

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to add the execution plan, don't put additional information into comments. You need to make sure to preserve the indention of the plan. [Edit] the question, paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. It is also more helpful if you post the plans for the _query_ themselves, not for calling the function.

Comment: Please show us the query plan from the SQL inside your function, not the (useless) plan from the function call.

Comment: @FrankHeikens is right. You should optimize your query first, and then wrap it into a stored function.  To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: You need to show an actual plan, not something that vaguely resembles one.  And preserve the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slow query, embeddded in your stored function, is this:

```sql
with data as (             -- original query from the question.
   select id,amount,account_nr from transfer
)
select * 
  from data d
 where (param_b or 1 < (select count(d2.account_nr) 
                        from data d2
                        where d2.id = d.id
                        group by d2.account_nr)
       )
   and (param_a or 0.00 <> (select sum(d2.amount)
                        from data d2
                        where d2.id = d.id)
       )
```

This has a pointless common table expression. We can get rid of it for simplicity's sake. You can always put it back if you need it for some other purpose.

And has a couple of [correlated subqueries](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-subqueries.php#MB). Let's refactor them into a single independent subquery. Starting with that independent subquery:

```sql
            select id, 
                   count(account_nr) account_count,
                   sum(amount) total_amount
              from transfer
             group by id
```

This aggregate subquery generates the number of accounts and the total amount for each `id` in your `transfer` table. Eyeball the results to convince yourself it does what you need it to do.

Then we can join this to the main query and apply your WHERE conditions.

```sql
select d.id, d.amount, d.account_nr 
  from transfer d
  join (
            select id, 
                   count(account_nr) account_count,
                   sum(amount) total_amount
              from transfer
             group by id
       )  d2 ON d.id = d2.id
 where (param_b or 1 < d2.account_count)
   and (param_a or 0.00 <> d2.total_amount)
```

Using the independent subquery can speed things up a lot; sometimes the query planner decides it needs to re-evaluate the dependent subquery many times.

The following index will help the subquery run faster.

```sql
CREATE INDEX id_details ON transfer (id) INCLUDE (account_nr, amount);
```

Convince yourself this works and is fast enough. (I did not debug it, because I don't have your data.) You'll need to test it substituting `true` and `false` for `param_a` and `param_b`.

Then, and only then, put it into your stored function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what i needed. Even without creating the Index my query is now fast enough.